# Has the US government done everything it can to prove the votes were counted correctly? If not, why not?

Tags: united-states, donald-trump, presidential-election

Some Trump supporters (including Trump himself) claim that votes were counted in an unfair way. Has the US government done everything possible to prove that Biden is the legitimate winner of the election, such as recounts in all contested states? If not, why not, if it could restore [peace](https://www.washingtonpost.com/dc-md-va/2021/01/06/dc-protests-trump-rally-live-updates/)? Is it that everything that reasonably could be done to prove that the count was done correctly, has already been done and these people are akin to conspiracy theorists who go buy a different set of logic?

Comment: Re *Is it that everything that reasonably could be done to prove that the count was done correctl?* Yes. This was a very secure and very fair election. People who only talk to fellow conspiracy theorists cannot imagine that anyone else cannot think the same way. People do occasionally vote in the name of the dead, or in the name of others. This is highly criminal, but these crimes are extremely small in number. Pennsylvania found after the fact that three of the millions of people who voted in the last election were in the names of dead people. All three of those dead people voted for Trump.

Comment: In the US, the states have the responsibility to oversee elections. To ask if "the US government [has] done everything ..." is to suggest the states haven't; thus discrediting the states.

Comment: @RickSmith While it is true that the Constitution explicitly delegates responsibility for elections to the states, the federal government can do some things to help the states conduct secure and fair elections, and the federal government does do some of those things.

Comment: This is a badly framed q as @Rick notes, but it has been argued on the left that e.g. Pence or McConnell took too long to speak out against the conspiracy theories. https://edition.cnn.com/2021/01/06/politics/mitch-mcconnell-trump-electoral-vote/index.html

Comment: … been unable to find *a single example* of widespread fraud, and only extremely tiny and irrelevant examples of individual fraud or even just honest mistakes, many of which actually *benefiting* Donald Trump is probably going to be the best we will get until there is a new administration.

Comment: I think the down votes were a bit harsh considering there were good answers given in comments and the main body

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Trump has been claiming the election would be fraudulent since [at least April of last year](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/blogs-trending-55009950). He also claimed that the [2016 election was fraudulent](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-us-canada-38126438), even though he won. At no point has he or any of his supporters provided any [evidence of the widespread fraud](https://www.theguardian.com/us-news/2020/dec/01/william-barr-no-evidence-voter-fraud) he has been claiming. Everything necessary to confirm the results has been done, but Trump refuses to accept the result and continues to spread misinformation and false claims of fraud. He is not interested in restoring peace, and has been actively stoking division and [riling up his supporters](https://www.cbsnews.com/news/trump-rally-electoral-college-vote-count/).

At this point there really is no controversy about the election result (there never was a controversy other than that manufactured by Trump himself) and the fraud narrative is being pushed only by Trump and sycophantic Republicans and media outlets who seem to think this will benefit them by ingratiating themselves with Trump's base, who won't just go away once Biden is president.

Aside from all of that, it is not the US (Federal) Government's responsibility to carry out elections. That is the responsibility of the individual state governments, each of which have certified that the results are accurate (after recounts where necessary) according to their own laws and processes.

Comment: @EkadhSingh I disagree with your edit. The word "sycophantic" was doing a lot of heavy lifting. It's not all Republicans and media outlets that are pushing the fraud narrative, only those that are sycophantic to Trump to the extent that they are denying reality.

Comment: Okay, my bad. You can roll back the edit.

Comment: @EkadhSingh Thanks. Normally I would agree that it's unnecessary and could be interpreted as bias. However in this case I think it's important to stress that there is no basis in reality for the fraud narrative and the only reason it's *still* being pursued is to appease Trump and his supporters.